# how to open new window in new tab with dynamic url

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, mouseevent

i have a page with drop down list and i have to open a new window with selected iteam's edit form

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.EntityGrid.Columns.Clear();
    EntityName.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
    newEntity.Visible = true;
    newEntity.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
    ...
}
```

the following works

```
protected void newEntity_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var entity = newEntity.Text;
    Response.Redirect(entity + "Edit.aspx");
    ...
}
```

but how can i open in separate tab not new window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a separate window is a client feature, so you need to "inject" the javascript that tells the browser to do this.

```
Response.Write(
     string.Format(
        "<script>window.open('{0}','_blank');</script>", entity + "Edit.aspx"));
```

The parameter `_blank` tells the `windows.open` function to open a new window

Comment: thank you Agustin popup is blocked how can i get it opened in new tab instead of new window

Comment: That's not a trivial problem... You can check the discussion on this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-url-in-new-tab-using-javascript

Answer (score 1):

You need to direct the browser to open a new window - this cannot be done server side, so you have to do so in client side.

One option is, instead of `Response.Redirect`, use `Response.Write` to output JavaScript to open a new window (and redirect the current one).

Another option is to use a `target="_blank"` attribute on a link that will open a new window.

Answer (score 0):

You can forget about using JavaScript because the browser controls whether or not it opens in a new tab. Your best option is to do something like the following instead:

```
<form action="http://www.yoursite.com/dosomething" method="get" target="_blank">
    <input name="dynamicParam1" type="text"/>
    <input name="dynamicParam2" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

This will always open in a new tab regardless of which browser a client uses due to the `target` attribute.